# How to query a key in a SQL Server Json column if it could be a scalar value or an object?

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-json

I have a table that with a column `Info VARCHAR(MAX)` constrained to always be valid json. What is the best way to query a key with JSON_QUERY/JSON_VALUE if I don't know ahead of time if the value associated with the key is a scalar or not? Currently I am returning where either has a value as shown below.

```
SELECT ID, JSON_VALUE(Info, '$.Key') as json_val, JSON_QUERY(Info,  '$.Key') as json_query
FROM TABLE
WHERE (JSON_VALUE(Info, '$.Key') IS NOT NULL OR JSON_QUERY(Info, '$.Key') IS NOT NULL)
```

and relying on the fact that the results are mutually exclusive.

The problem is the `JSON_QUERY` in the `WHERE` clause prevents any indexes on the virual column `vKey AS JSON_VALUE(Info, '$.Key')` from being used.

Comment: One possibility might be to define the computed column as `vKey AS ISNULL(JSON_VALUE(Info, '$.Key'), JSON_QUERY(Info,  '$.Key') )` and then change the query to `SELECT ID, CASE WHEN ISJSON(vKey) = 0 THEN vKey END as json_val, CASE WHEN ISJSON(vKey) = 1 THEN vKey END  as json_query FROM "TABLE"  WHERE vKey IS NOT NULL`

Comment: a scalar function that returns (select o.value from openjson(@info) as o where o.[key] = 'key') ..a computed column as dbo.f(info) and an index on the computed column

Comment: @Martin Smith Thanks for your suggestion. Virtual columns backed by `JSON_QUERY` can't be used in an index. using `ISNULL` how you show does seem to allow it to be created, but it isn't being used in the query plan.

Comment: you probably have to `INCLUDE (ID)` to make the index covering. This would only be suitable if the potential object returned by `JSON_QUERY(Info,  '$.Key')` is always going to be short enough to fit into an index key (<= 1700 bytes)

Comment: Execution plan using this index https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyAEh.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @MartinSmith, you can add a computed column like this

```sql
ALTER TABLE YourTable
  ADD YourColumn AS (ISNULL(JSON_VALUE(json, '$.key'), JSON_QUERY(json, '$.key')));
```

You can then index it, and the index will be used in queries automatically

```sql
CREATE INDEX IndexName ON YourTable (YourColumn) INCLUDE (OtherColumns)
```

Note that the index will normally be used even if you use the original expression rather than the new column name.

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2c80d5a2f31dfaa687b87194af28809a)